# CSS - Selector for " ..... " in a form_for

Tags: css, form-for

I'm trying to add some style on a specific label of my form_for. 
My form_for has been created like this :

<%= f.input :description, label: " description" %>

I can modify all the label thank's to :

```
.form-control-label {
  margin-left: 118px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

But I want to play with one specific ;

description

I tried so many things with required"" , 
I tried to put a class in the label but I don't know how to do with Bootsrap, 
I tried to add :child, ...

But I don't find how to do ....

I started to code 3 months ago and I'm stuck for few days now :)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the rendered html for this label?

As you said you've already tried adding an extra css class to modify this label specifically. Have you tried inspecting the element using chrome dev tools or any other? Should be a pretty straight forward fix for this one.

```
<div>
<label class="generic">I'm a label</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
<label class="generic">I'm a label</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
<label class="generic special">I'm a label</label>
<input type="text" />
</div>
.generic{color: red; font-size: 18px;}
.special{color: blue; }
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMomWQ